# What's the difference between static cells and dynamic prototypes?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to know the difference between making the cells in my `UITableView` "Static Cells" or choosing "Dynamic Prototypes".

If I want to make a `UITableView` that has a "+" button to add cells (like Contacts App or Clock when setting an alarm). Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Static cells are basically a "what you see is what you get" in Interface Builder. What you put into the `UITableView` is what you'll see when you run the app.

Dynamic prototypes, instead, allow you to lay out cells that you can re-use by calling:

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID_SET_IN_IB];
```

With this, you determine the number of cells using the delegate methods in the `UITableViewController`. You can have multiple prototype cells and determine which to load depending on index path.

You can use segues with both.

I would recommend prototypes for your app since it seems like, from your question, the number of cells you have will change.